# How to fix "ImportError: No module named request"

Tags: python

I'm trying to import requests for `urllib2` and keep on getting an import error:

> ImportError: No module named request

I'm trying to learn how to use `urllib2` but just can't even get it started.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")

print(html)
```

I am not sure what the outcome of this is supposed to be, but hopefully I can get it working. It does autofill urllib2 in imports, so it's there.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, what version of python is installed on your system?

Comment: Also, what IDE are you using? For instance, I've had it that a package was installed on my system but not in the virtual environment I was using in pycharm

Comment: Please try it on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler the code you shared works. Please update the Python version.
documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html
Welcome to the SO.

Comment: @Gramatik I am using WingPersonal for this.

Comment: Open cmd and run "pip list", or the equivalent of getting the list of locally installed python packages on your OS if not windows. I would also suggest adding python to PATH if you've not done so. If you don't see urllib in the list you have the answer, otherwise its likely an IDE-specific thing. Also, I have that package installed as urllib3 instead of urllib2, that could be part of it